# Proof with sequences: if A is a closed set, exists a countable set dense in A

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to proof the following, but i fail to concil the problem with the hint:

> If $X\subset R$ is closed, show that exists a sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in N}$ such that $\forall a\in X$ exists a subsequence $n_{i}\rightarrow\infty$ with $a_{n_{i}}\rightarrow a$, i.e., $a_{n}$ accumulates in all points of X.

The hint is to proof if A is a closed set, exists a countable set dense in A.

Comment: Any subset of a separable metric space is separable. So any subset of $\mathbb R$ is separable u nder the usual metric.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to extend Kavi's comment: the rationals are countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so take an enumeration of those as your sequence (removing all that aren't inside $X$).

Edit: as pointed out by José this only works if $X$ contains the rationals. For an explicit construction otherwise take an enumeration of the rationals $(q_n)_n$ and an arbitrary element $x_0 \in X$. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ pick $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(q_n) \cap X$ if this intersection is not empty, else pick $x_n := x_0$. That way we get a sequence in $X$ which is dense in $X$:
For arbitrary $a\in X$ there is a subsequence of $(q_n)_n$ converging to $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$, say $(q_{n_i})_i$. Then $$|a-x_{n_i}| \leq |a - q_{n_i}| + |q_{n_i} - x_{n_i}| \leq |a - q_{n_i}| + \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$$
I think this should work now.

Comment: I think that you are wasting your time. It is quite likely that the question will be closed and deleted anyway. Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1) to see why.